# How to downgrade bazel to 0.4.3

Tags: bazel

I installed bazel and upgrade it to 0.4.4 recently.

I want to try [tensorflow/models/syntaxnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet) but it requires bazel 0.4.3.

So how can I downgrade bazel 0.4.4 to 0.4.3?

Comment: Did you succeed with 0.4.3? I've had an error, I've downgraded, and I still have the same error (6 tests failed).

Comment: I didn't run the tests. Maybe you can ask or create an issue on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0.4.4 should work fine, too.  0.4.3 is the minimum.

If you really want, you can install 0.4.3 from [the installer](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.4.3).

Comment: I find the cached bazel deb file in /var/cache/apt/archives directory. And [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2478) is the issue that bazel 0.4.4 does not work. I've downgraded it to 0.4.3 now.

Comment: I mean, you can also just update the tensorflow submodule (as suggested on the issue) and 0.4.4 will work fine.